# Why its so hard to get only 1 row mysql data into android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I only want to use JSON data from an URL as a variable in my activity.
It works without problem with listview-arrays, but thats too long for my wish I guess.
What should I do? I found some examples, but httpclient is deprecated now. I don't want to downgrade my library because of that.

For example, I can use a data from json data as header in my toolbar. How can I do?

my php-json side;

```
$uid= $_GET['device_id'];

$result = "SELECT `contact_name`,`username`,`device_id` FROM `users` WHERE `device_id`='{$uid}' AND `device_match`=1 AND `suspended`=0 LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($result);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num>0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["contact_name"] = $row['contact_name'];
    $response["link"] = "index.php";
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["contact_name"] = "";
    $response["link"] = "login.php";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

I like to use these datas inside;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.portal_activity);

    // I know thats stupid, just for explanation what I want to do.

    final String username = $response["contact_name"];
    final String link= $response["link"];


    //like below;
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle(username);

    //or like to set into a textview;

    TextView mytext1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext1);
    mytext1.setText(link);
}
```

My skill level: pretty good at PHP, beginner at Android/Java

Comment: your code is wide open to **SQL-Injections** - just imagine someone sending the UID `'; DROP TABLE users -- ` - please use parameterized queries to protect you from that security flaw. for this, use `mysqli` or `PDO`-functions, since `mysql`-functions have been deprecated for a while now, and in PHP7, are completely **removed**

Comment: whats the problem in your code?

Comment: I know, I just write the cod clear because of my request. I also protect my pages. my php pages accesible only from my app with some user agent techniques.

Comment: @Karthi problem I dont know how to call and fetch my json data in onCreate method.

Comment: the "user agent" is just a string sent by the browser. it can be faked. very, very, very easily. rule number one about code safety: **never** trust user input.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your return type inside your header.

```
header('Content-type: javascript/json');
// TODO: Add logic here
echo json_encode($response);
```

Also note that your SQL may be vulnerable to SQL injections, treat GET/POST data as **un-trusted** sources. You do not know what they contain, so never directly append them to your SQL.

Example of using a less depreciated driver:

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=some_db', 'some_user', 'some_pass');
// ? is a placeholder
$smpt = $con->Prepare('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col = ?');
// add the value to the placeholder securely
$smpt->execute(['someValue']);
$result = $smpt->fetch();
```

Also, be careful with the information you're return in your response because anyone can reverse engineer your application and send malicious ID's and get user information. Consider using [handshakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking).

Comment: thanks guys for sql injection warnings. But I really dont have problem there. I just made the code shorter. have enough filter functions on php side. My problem in java side.

Comment: Are you sure? `json_encode()` needs `true` as a second param & if someone reverse engineers your requests inside the APP and find this URI, the can send malicious ID's.

Comment: `json_encode()` does *not* take a boolean as second [parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-parameters). `json_decode()` does, though.

Comment: Didn't know that, although [it works](https://3v4l.org/lV4ST) using it. @FranzGleichmann

Comment: @KDOT because PHP implicitely casts the boolean to an integer - possibly leaving you with unexpected results. you should adapt your answer.

Comment: just for info. My app only accesible from registered users.Registration not online. that informations in our school server. Only allowed users can run the app. and users are just teachers. my app generates unique device IDs for each user/phone and these informations are on my database. If no match, app gives warning them. if matches, allowed activities running on their phones. And, I know have to use pdo instead of this. Its just a ritual when I write quick code as above.that wasnt the full code of php.Btw all strings already preformatted before inserting on the DB. so I dont worry about it.

Comment: expect the unexpected.